# And you do not love

Tags: grammar

What's the emphasis of such forms as "and you do not love me" instead of "you don't love"? I also heard in this movie "why can you not understand? Insted of "why can't you understand?" Are they old-fashioned and formal in modern English?

https://youtu.be/mnfe9wjcHGY

At 1:36

Comment: This is obviously a period drama, so the scriptwriters have sometimes used the full forms of verbs to give an 'old-fashioned' flavour to the dialogue. In modern speech, we sometimes use uncontracted forms for emphasis. "Would you like to come mountain-climbing with me?" "No, _I would not!_ I was terrified last time."

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing, it is strongly recommended to avoid using contractions like "don't". Also:

> This is obviously a period drama, so the scriptwriters have sometimes used the full forms of verbs to give an 'old-fashioned' flavour to the dialogue. In modern speech, we sometimes use uncontracted forms for emphasis. "Would you like to come mountain-climbing with me?" "No, I would not! I was terrified last time." - @KateBunting

Contractions "work quite well in natural, informal dialogue" - [Source](https://www.simplyscripts.net/cgi-bin/Blah/Blah.pl?b-screenwrite/m-1328569459/)

Comment: I admire your enthusiasm, DialFrost, but your first link refers to the contraction _cont'd_ which is used in writing, never in speech.

Comment: Enthusiasm? (sorry not sure what you meant there :P). Oh sorry Ill find another source @KateBunting

Comment: I meant the enthusiasm with which you so often jump in and provide an answer!

Comment: Is that a bad thing? :P thanks @KateBunting

Comment: I said I admired it, didn't I? - but I sometimes disagree with your conclusions.

Comment: Sorry @KateBunting, my english isnt very good :(